# Parsing JSON results with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, json, search-engine

I'm trying to build a metasearch engine, and have the following code which generates JSON results.

```
<?php

$search = $_GET['results'];
if(isset($_GET['results']) && $_GET['results'] != "")
{

    echo "<br />Your Search Result Array:<br /><br />";

$url = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&"
    . "q=".str_replace(' ', '%20', $_GET['results']);

$ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.google.com');
$body = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);


$json = json_decode($body);

print_r($json);
```

This gives me  JSON unsorted results, without an order or hyperlinks. I am trying to parse to results using PHP. When I type "hello" into the search engine it gives me

```
stdClass Object ( [responseData] => stdClass Object ( [results] => Array ( [0] =>stdClass Object ( [GsearchResultClass] => GwebSearch [unescapedUrl] => http://www.hellomagazine.com/ [url] => http://www.hellomagazine.com/ [visibleUrl] => www.hellomagazine.com [cacheUrl] => http://www.google.com/search?q=cache:QzMhUCC4zBoJ:www.hellomagazine.com [title] => HELLO! Online: celebrity & royal news, magazine, babies,
```

as the first 4 lines.  I tried

```
foreach($results['responsedata']['results']['GsearchResultsClass'] as $result)
{

echo $result['title'].'<br/>';
}
```

but it leaves me with tonnes of errors on the foreach line.

Any advice greatly appreciated, i am not familiar with JSON so any help is welcome on how to parse the results.

Comment: Because `$results` isn't an array. `var_dump($results);` and see. Also check for the second parameter of `json_decode()`

Comment: If you want to access it as an array, change the [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) line to: `$json = json_decode($body, true);`

Comment: Provide me your complete json key=>value output. Please use `$json = json_decode($json, true);` to get the proper output.

Comment: Side note, why do you assign `$search = $_GET['results'];` when you never use `$search` and always refer to it as `$_GET['results']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your using the default return type of `json_encode`, which returns a stdClass object. If you want to consume it as a associative array then pass this following parameter to json_decode.

```
$json = json_decode($json, true);
```